# How to Fix Redirect Issue, Ive already tried tons of solutions (Codes) Already

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a website, being hosted on a hosting server. I have already uploaded the site but the moment I access the domain example.com, it opens up a directory of all the files in the folder, rather than the index.html.

I know its something with .htaccess file, but Ive tried with every possible code but its not working and sometimes the error appears saying "Internal Server Error" etc. The moment I delete the htaccess file it again works fine but again showing up the directory.

As mentioned Ive almost tried with every thing possible.

Additional Info:-
By default, there was some #wordpress code within htaccess with few if conditions(Ive already deleted the wordpress stuff and created a new htaccess) and the only issue was it wasn't redirecting the domain to index.html(Home). But now since as mentioned above when I delete the htaccess directory shows up and when I do click on the index.html file from the directory it opens the home page.. but after deleting that wordpress code ive now also unable to navigate other pages (such as about.html, contact.html etc) and the error status as "Internal Server Error" but only the index.html works once clicked from the directory.

This is the code of the .htaccess I had by default.

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 10 minutes"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 hours"
</IfModule>
Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Website:- http://almishkatkw.com

Thank You

Comment: can you mention which hosting server you are using ?

Comment: bluehost it is.

Comment: Sounds like the `DirectoryIndex` directive is not configured correclty: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: thank you.. but this neither helped.. earlier Ive tried this though

Comment: comment line by line or block of block of .htaccess file and say what line if commented, solves problem. and send full htaccess contents here.

Comment: You have tried _what_ ? Please add your attempts to the question. Thanks.

Comment: updated the question